# Can memory compatibility depend on the selected CPU?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

Up until recently I always thought memory compatibility was completely dependent on the motherboard and the processor didn't make a difference when it came to memory compatibility. However, I was reading that the Sandy Bridge line of Intel Core processors ["support up to DDR3-1333 memory"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155#Original_Sandy_Bridge_chipsets). So, my question is what if I use a Sandy Bridge processor with DDR3-1600 memory? Will the system simply not work, run at DDR3-1333 speeds, or will it run at DDR3-1600 speeds?

More specifically, this is the board, memory and processor I was looking at:

- [ASUS SABERTOOTH Z77](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131821)
- [Intel Core i3-2105 Sandy Bridge 3.1GHz](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115090)
- [G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 16GB (4 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231429)

Both the processor and the memory are listed on the motherboard's CPU and memory support list.

Comment: Why do you have new everything else? If you got a huge truck with a small electric motor, how well would it run?

Comment: Already have the processor, trying to build a budget system that will last along time. I can upgrade the processor later when I get more money.

Comment: Alrighty, just checking... cause it sounds like over kill otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On modern PCs, the memory controller is part of the CPU. So the CPU can impose limits on the memory speed. If you use a Sandy Bridge processor with DDR3-1600 memory, it will run at DDR3-1333 speeds (though with improved latency) unless you overclock the memory controller.